# Unrecognized expression: :nth-child

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am getting the follow error:

> unrecognized expression: :nth-child

The following is the code relating to this problem:

```
var path = $("#quickSearchContainer > ul > li:nth-child(i + 1)");

function resetSearch() {                      
  for (i = 0; i < SectorCheck.length; i++) {            
    console.log(path.text());
    console.log(SectorCheck[i]);
    if ((path.text()) === SectorCheck[i]) {
      path.hide()
    }   
  }
}
```

Note: if I change the `(i + 1)` to a number only, it works, but it is not what is needed.

Comment: What is `i` meant to be? CSS selectors don't have variables. Separately: I strongly suspect `:nth-child` isn't what you want. It doesn't mean "the nth `li` in the `ul`", it means "an `li` in the `ul` that's also the nth child of the `ul`" (which in the case of `ul` and `li` might be the same thing, but in most cases won't be).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you're trying to index into `path` with `i`. If so, nothing is going to magically insert the value of your `i` variable into the selector, especially as it's already been executed.

To index into `path`, use `[i]` (to get the raw DOM element) or `.eq(i)` (to get a jQuery wrapper around the element at that position), see comments:

```
var path = $("#quickSearchContainer > ul > li"); // Removed :nth-child(i + 1)

function resetSearch(){

    for (var i = 0; i < SectorCheck.length; i++) {  
    //   ^^^----- remember to declare your variables

        // Get the entry for `i` (as a jQuery object)
        var entry = path.eq(i);
        if (entry.text() === SectorCheck[i]) {
            entry.hide()
        }   
    }
}
```

Also note that you need to declare `i`. Your code was falling prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) by not declaring it.